# expressionengine No content after SQL import

Tags: phpmyadmin, expressionengine

I've recently pushed the staging DB to the prod DB so it would reflect changes. Now no content shows up. No pages or channels. The content is in the DB.

No files were pushed. The only thing that changed was the DB content.

Edit:

I was mistaken. I see the content in the CMS, but site loads blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory issue. Increased to 256M and the site loaded. A bit insane if you ask me...